# Dataset with less yes (6%) and more No (94%). All classifier algorithms (ANN, C4, CART) in SPSS predicts all values as No in test set. What do i do?

Tags: r, statistics, classification, spss, data-science

Dataset with less yes (6%) and more No (94%). All classifier algorithms (ANN, C4, CART) in SPSS predicts all values as No in test set. What do i do?

The data has around 2500 rows and 85 columns.

Comment: You have tagged this as R related. Do you have any R code that could make this relevant? You also have a massive class imbalance as I read between the lines which doesn't surprise with the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into oversampling techniques as for example implemented in R by the `SMOTE` function in the `DMwR package`.

Here is a short tutorial: http://amunategui.github.io/smote/
and here a Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Mt7EuVJf1A

> The SMOTE function oversamples your rare event by using bootstrapping
>   and k-nearest neighbor to synthetically create additional observations
>   of that event. The definition of rare event is usually attributed to
>   any outcome/dependent/target/response variable that happens less than
>   15% of the time.

Comment: Thanks :) Exactly what I was looking for!